# Drainage pipe in ground

Tags: drain, drainage

I just discovered that my 2 inch PVC drainage pipe output was buried at about 6 inches below my front lawn. I tried to make a makeshift 1 inch trench to help the water flow out. The problem is that my driveway and sidewalk gets dirt and mud when it rains hard. Would like a few recommendations on something I can do myself.

[image: PVC Drain pipe underground]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf4os.jpg) are a couple of other photos.

Comment: The last 3 pics don't help much, since we have no idea how eater drains or where the mystery pipe would be in those pics.  Overview pics or markings would help.

Comment: The pipe in question is the one in the dirt perpendicular to the one on top coming out from the wall. Right now water it's draining into the hole I dug to find the pipe. I would prefer to have it drain straight to the street gutter. Not sure what it's the best way to accomplish this. I guess I'd dig a wider and deeper trench and try to pass the pipe below the sidewalk.